# Plot vertical line between 2 values at the same factor

Tags: r, plot

I have data for several factors i'd like to plot.
For each factor I have values A, B, C, D.
I can plot all datapoints by

```
plot(A, col="blue")
points(B, col="red")
points(C, col="cyan")
points(D, col="green")
```

This gives me a perfect graph with my 4 properties per factor.

But I would love to have - instead of 4 points - only 2 points for A and B and a vertical line spanning from C to D. How would I do that?

EDIT:
Sorry for missing the dataset:

```
set.seed(42)
names <- c(5, 5, 10, 10, 15)
A <- sample(5) + 10; B <- sample(5) + 10; C <- sample(5) + 5; D <- sample(5)
data <- data.frame(names, A, B, C, D)
data
#  names  A  B  C D
#1     5 11 14  9 2
#2     5 15 12  6 5
#3    10 14 15 10 3
#4    10 13 11  7 1
#5    15 12 13  8 4
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. Please provide a complete reproducible example including all inputs in reproducible form (see info at top of [tag:r] tag page) and clarify the expected output.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I added the inputs.

Comment: Which answer will you accept?

Comment: I will accept mine as soon as I can (still locked for 18 hours)

Comment: Poor form, Peter

Comment: Well, thanks r2evans, you helped me out a lot, but your answer was not the solution I expected. So I answered it myself, now that I know how it works. I don't see a "poor form" here - or what do you mean?

Comment: Your answer is almost exactly the same as mine: `plot` then `points` then `segments`. The answer to your question was informing you about the segments function and how to use it with four vectors. Whether those are four independent vectors (as when your question started) or four columns of a frame is moot. Just like questions don't need to be all of your actual production code, answers don't always need to include every detail of the question's code to address the core issue.

Comment: I stated "For each factor I have values", which implies dependence to me. Also I asked for "vertical lines" which you did not provide. Still: thank you for the assist!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I updated the question to include the data set definition.
This is the solution to my problem:

```
plot(data$A, ylim=c(0,15), col="blue", pch=20, xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", main="")
axis(1, at=seq(0.5, nrow(data), 1)+0.5, labels=data$names)

points(data$B, col="red", pch=20)

# now draw lines between C and D points for each data row
segments(x0=seq_along(data$A), y0=data$C, x1=seq_along(data$A), y1=data$D, col="cyan", lwd=5)
```

Which results in vertical bars/lines between each data rows C and D points.

[image: solution]

Kudos to [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans) for pointing in the right direction!

Comment: You're using `seq_along` incorrectly here. It is sequencing along the number of *columns*, but you should be sequencing along the number of *rows*. What you need is `seq_len(nrow(data))` for that. It happens to work here because you have a square frame, but you may not always be so lucky.

Comment: true, I fixed it in my real case. I used `seq_along(data$A)` which worked out. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`segments`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/segments.html).

```r
set.seed(42)
A <- sample(5); B <- sample(5); C <- sample(5); D <- sample(5)
A
# [1] 1 5 4 3 2
B
# [1] 4 2 5 1 3
C
# [1] 4 1 5 2 3
D
# [1] 2 5 3 1 4
plot(A, col="blue")
points(B, col="red")
segments(seq_along(C), seq_along(D), C, D, col="green")
```

[image: base R graphic with random points/lines]

Comment: that was the right hint. see my own answer.